# Outputting a list in Haskell without the brackets, and over a range?

Tags: list, haskell

I have a function that returns a list, call it `f n`.

If I print the list, it looks like `[1,2,3,4]` whereas I want it to look like `1 2 3 4`.

Also I want to output many lists over a range of `n`, so `f 1` on the first line, `f 2` on the second line, ... `f n` on the nth line.

I have my `f n` function working but cannot get the output to work for the life of me.

Current attempt:

```
main = do
    n <- readLn :: IO Int
    mapM_ putStrLn [f i | i <- [1..n]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like

```
list_to_string = unwords . map show
```

to get the output format you want. Then instead of doing

```
print [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

you can do

```
putStrLn $ list_to_string $ [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

which should display how you want.

**Edit:** As for printing a range, try this:

```
main = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  mapM_ (putStrLn . list_to_string) [ f i | i <- [1..n] ]
```

Comment: What about outputting f n over a range?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that part of your question. Are you saying that `f` takes a number and returns a list of numbers?

Comment: What was wrong with the code I posted? Why does this work but not mine?

Comment: `putStrLn` prints a `String`. Not a number or a list or anything else, only a `String`. You need some other function to convert it to a string first. `mapM_ print` would work (but wouldn't give you the formatting you're after here).